# Bootstrap sticky menu in WordPress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have a menu which I have assigned the affix class using the JS and the data-spy methods but it doesn't work, there are no JS errors in my console (firefox or chrome) and the js and css of BS are at 3.3.1. I am using WordPress, the files are all enqueued and everything else works fine.

I have deactivated all the plugins (although none use BS), I have deleted all the other scripts I enqueued

Navigation HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav" rol="navigation">
```

My Affix JS is:

```
jQuery('#nav').affix({
  offset: {
   top: 580
  }
 });
```

Anyone able to point me in a direction to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I see that jQuery is loading in the source, but I did not see the bootstrap js file. Here is an example of how you would properly enqueue bootstrap into WordPress and set jQuery as dependency.

[Github Gist to enqueue Bootstrap](https://gist.github.com/mrbobbybryant/83c4a076da6dd67de3da)

Comment: Bootstrap is registered in the footer along with the other scripts, BS is properly enqueued as it's adding the affix-top class to the nav but when you scroll down it's supposed to change to affix.